# Modifying an accordion to behave like a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

For 4 hours I have been trying to modify the accordion template to look and feel like a table row. Essentially, I want to have a table where each row element is an accordion group that when clicked on will collapse/show more details about that particular item.

I want it to have a feel similar to this (excuse the poor markup, just a demo):

http://plnkr.co/edit/VX0tRxIuKzoz0cKy39PY?p=preview

So far this is probably the closest I have gotten to:

http://plnkr.co/edit/0tD8xcHJknTQhXQgABXJ?p=preview

Could someone enlighten me, step by step, on how to make the accordion look like the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617030/ng-grid-expand-and-collaspe-row/29177750#29177750). It gives an example of how to achieve this expand/collapse table using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end.